# Obtaining CSR Format from a Given Symmetric Sparse Matrix

Tags: csr

I am very new to the use of sparse matrices for solving simultaneous equations. I want to use them for solving problems in FEA.

Is there a FORTRAN routine, or a function in the Intel Math Kernel library from which I can obtain the compressed row format (CSR) for a given symmetric matrix?

I can then use the CSR to solve my system of linear equations using the 'pardiso' routine in the Fortran MKL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.intel.com/software/products/mkl/docs/webhelp/bla/functn_mkl_ddnscsr.html#functn_mkl_ddnscsr

Comment: The link is broken. Could you please explain what was there?